# Android - VideoView shows thumbnail of previous video

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I made a video player based on VideoView widget. The videos are loaded from internet.
Everything works fine, except one little thing.

I open a video, and while it is playing I click the "Next" button to advance to the next video. And the issue is that while the next video is loading, it shows me the thumbnail of previous video. 
I would like to not display any thumbnail, or at least the thumbnail of currently loading video, but deffinetly NOT the thumbnail of previous video.

So, is there a method like "flush()", or something like this to clear the videovideo and not show the thumbn. of previous video? Or at least why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid off that thumbnail, it was necessary to re-creating the VideoView when clicking Next/Prev buttons. Maybe not one of the best solution, but at least it solved the issue.